# Magento - How to add step images to checkout

Tags: magento, checkout

I am trying to show a progress overview at the top of the one page checkout page in Magento. 
I have the step icons and I have the different states (complete, current, active etc) but I'm a little lost on how I hook in to the accordion to determine the states?

On each panel I could edit it and add to the onclick event something like this:

```
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="updateOpcProgress('login');checkout.setMethod();">......
```

Then I in my updateOpcProgress() function change the css class of my progress image to whatever it needs to be.

That would work but it seems a really inefficient way of doing it (plus I would have to override all the panels phtml files) (plus it wouldn't work if they Edit a section - unless I also call the function on the edit click!)

Any one have a better idea of how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using the progress block that is already on the page, and just redesign it?

Otherwise, if you prefer to make a new progress bar, you can modify the onepage checkout Javascript in opcheckout.js. You don't have to modify the file, you can add your own .js file and override some of the checkout functions, like this:

```
Checkout.prototype.gotoSection = function(section)
{
    section = $('opc-'+section);
    section.addClassName('allow');
    this.accordion.openSection(section);
    // Call your own progress updater:
    updateOpcProgress(section);
};
```

Comment: I want to have the progress block also but your other idea was just what I was looking for! Thank you.